# Pattern Matching in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a results something like this format..

```
[
  ok: {:ok,
   %MyApp.Message{
     account_sid: "asdsad",
     api_version: "2010-04-01",
     body: "hi",
     direction: "outbound-api",
     from: nil,
     num_media: "0",
     num_segments: "0",
     sid: "asdsad",
     status: "accepted",
     subresource_uri: nil,
     to: "+15005550000",
   }},
  ok: {:ok,
   %MyApp.Message{
     account_sid: "asdasd",
     api_version: "2010-04-01",
     body: "hi",
     direction: "outbound-api",
     from: nil,
     num_media: "0",
     num_segments: "0",
     sid: "asdasd",
     status: "accepted",
     subresource_uri: nil,
     to: "+15005550000",
   }}
]
```

and I want to convert to 
[ {account_sid, status}, {account_sid, status}]
for eachh item in list

How can I do this using Elixir function?

Comment: May I ask where this output comes from? Just curious.

Comment: I am using Twilio API. results returns from Twilio API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answer given by @MateuszBielawski is technically correct, I would do it in safer way using [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension (I altered the input a bit):

```rb
input = [
  ok: {:ok, %{foo: :bar1, baz: 42}},
  ok: {:error, %{foo: :bar, baz: 42}},
  error: :some,
  ok: {:ok, %{foo: :bar2, boo: 42}}

for {:ok, {:ok, %{foo: foo}}} <- input, do: foo
#⇒ [:bar1, :bar2]
```

Advantages of this approach are:

- it’s more succinct
- it won’t hang up on unexpected keys (filtering them out, see the third line of the input)
- it won’t hang up on unexpected values (filtering them out, see the second line of the input)
- it allows additional filtering and/or altering the iterated data on the fly (see the linked documentation).

Answer (score 2):

Keywords in Elixir are in reality a tuple of {:keyword, value}, so you could write it like this:

```
Enum.map(result, fn {:ok, {:ok, %MyApp.Message{status: status, account_sid: sid}}} -> 
    {sid, status}
end)
```